# in LSTM and GRU, what factor has size of memory?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

As you know, RNN(Recurrent Neural Network) is for a short-term memory model. So, LSTM and GRU come out to deal with the problem.

My question is if I have to train a model to remember more long sequences, which are the features of my dataset, than others. What factor should be modified in the Layer?

The model structure is:

```
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((96, 6))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(96, 6))(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(192, return_sequences=True))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(192, dropout=dropout))(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)

    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(576, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

You can see this concept in the below references.

[What is the meaning of "The number of units in the LSTM cell"?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12964/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-number-of-units-in-the-lstm-cell#:%7E:text=The%20number%20of%20units%20in%20a%20RNN%20is%20the%20number,information%20to%20next%20memory%20units.)

[Understanding LSTM units vs. cells](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241985/understanding-lstm-units-vs-cells)

But, their answers are somewhat abstract. I think that the units are a replication of input data, which can play a role in preventing a model from overfitting. Also, I think of this function as a self-ensemble option.